# Identifying a process via a "key"

Tags: windows, process

Is it possible to identify a process via a key?

For example, suppose Server Process 1 starts Chrome Web App Process 1 (Chrome web apps are their own processes). Now suppose I start Server Process 2. I can already detect if Server Process 1 is running (actually, this causes an exception due to the need for a shared resource which I catch). So I'm going to terminate Server Process 2, except first I want check if Chrome Web App Process 1 is still running, because, if it is, I don't want to open up a new instance, but instead just bring the old instance to the front.

Suppose I could associate the key "com.myuniqueurl" with Chrome Web App Process 1. Then it'd be easy to search for any processes with the key "com.myuniqueurl" when Server Process 2 starts. Is this possible?

Part of the difficulty is that in addition to Chrome Web App Process 1, normal instances of Chrome may be running (from the same .exe file).

Comment: With the Win32 API this is easy (use a named event or named mailslot).  But I don't know if you can do it with mechanisms available to web apps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think this is not possible without nasty hacks like running something from within the Chrome process using CreateRemoteThread.

But in your case you might be able to enumerate processes, identify Chrome Web App Process 1 by its command-line and bring it to the front.